# Is there a way to edit spesific cells in Xamarin.forms.datagrid?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms.Datagrid to display my data in grid format. I'm just wondering is there a way of editing specific cells in the datagrid?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow OrderRow in dgvItemDetails.Rows)
{
    if (OrderRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == 
    DcoNumScanned.ToString() &&  OrderRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() 
    == _ItemCode)
{
        OrderRow.Cells[4].Value = 
        (Convert.ToDouble(OrderRow.Cells[4].Value) - 
        Convert.ToDouble(_uomQty));
        break;
        }
}
```

The above is just an example that I have.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: yes, modify the underlying datasource the grid is bound to

Comment: Thanks Jason. Sorry for being a boob can you maybe give me an example?

Comment: not really, since you didn't provide any detail about the datasource you're using.  But generally whatever property `Cells[4]` is bound to, you would just modify that

Comment: see my example below

Comment: Please  take time to edit your code you will see also u have an extra bracket in your code that should not be their @Fourie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say your DataGrid is bound to a `List<Widget>`

```
foreach(var w in widgets)
{
   if (w.ID == DcoNumScanned.ToString() && w.Code == _ItemCode)
   {
      w.Price -= Convert.ToDouble(_uomQty));
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason I'll try it when I'm back in the office

Comment: Thanks this did the trick